# Warning: Illegal string offset PHP cart and mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

what in the following code is causeing Warning: Illegal string offset 'quantity' in ' because of PHP 5.4 version cant find a fix?

```
    <?php

        include "data.php"; 

       function checkStock($id_film){
          $query_stock =  "SELECT stockquantity FROM table WHERE id = {$id_film}";
          $result_stock = mysql_query($query_stock);
          $row = mysql_fetch_row($result_stock);
          echo $row[0]['quantity'];  //this where the error is
       }
```

Comment: I bet you just want `$row['quantity'];` - did you try `var_dump($row);` to see what's actually in it?

Comment: quick reply this is the error  echo $row[0]['quantity'];  and var_dump($row); does seem to get rid of the error

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to debug, you could write:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result_stock);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
echo "</pre>";
```

That will give you an idea about what the array looks like. From your MYSQL query, it's probably going to be like:

```
Array(
  "quantity" => 5
)
```

So, this should work:

```
echo $row['quantity']; 

instead of

echo $row[0]['quantity'];
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: echo $row[0]['quantity']; without [0] it doesn't show the value which what i need

Comment: Well, could you do the print_r thing and let me know the array you get, please?

Comment: best answer so far. 

Array
(
    [0] => 1
)

Out of stock

Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
one product is instock

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory chastisement: Don't use the `mysql` API; it's deprecated and has been removed completely from PHP 7. Now that that's out of the way...

`$row = mysql_fetch_row($result_stock);` returns a ***single row*** of data as a ***one-dimensional array.*** Your reference to `$row[0]['quantity']` is attempting to dereference a ***two-dimensional array***, so of course you're getting an error because the second dimension doesn't exist.

rjdown is correct; you just want `$row['quantity']` which selects the `quantity` column of the *current* row.

Comment: i know php7 is out im using php5 i have no choice. any ideas on getting it working using this version?

Comment: My answer is for the `mysql` API. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You have used mysql_fetch_row which returns single row of database as an array which you can access information like $row[0], $row[1], ... In your case it seems that you are accessing one field of a unique record then you have only one field to be returned if found or null if not found. If you want to access information like an associated array use mysql_fetch_assoc then the result will be stored in an associated array like $row['quantity'].
So try to edit this part

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result_stock); echo $row[0]['quantity'];
```

Like this

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_stock); echo $row['quantity'];
```

Comment: its for stock control so if item out of stock 'out ' is displayed the idea is to stop user going any further with an order